# ibm bluemix natural language classifier /

Tags: service, classification, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I am trying to test the new Natural Language Classifier service on IBM Bluemix. Unfortunately the web address mentioned seems to be unavailable : 
https://gateway-watsonplatform.net/natural-language-classifier-beta/api/v1/classifiers

Can you help ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

There is one typo (or more) in your URL above. It should read "gateway.watsonplatform.net" (without a dash). However, this is still not an address you should use directly or in a browser: That URL is the API entry point, which you should GET or POST accordingly to the [service documentation](https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/nl-classifier) (see also the [API reference](https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/apis/#!/natural-language-classifier)).

When you create a service instance in [Bluemix](http://www.bluemix.net/), you will obtain a set of "credentials", including a username and password, and also the correct URL as a base path for the APIs. *That is the URL you should use* (which may vary, so it should not be included here as a solution).